# How can I sync a Node js app, git, and Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have a Node.js app. I have it hosted and running on Heroku. The folder `C:\projects\test` has my Node.js code, such as `package.json`, `node_modules\`, a `.git\` folder that points to a git repository, and a Heroku `Procfile`.

I want to be able to run Heroku commands using `cmd` but realized it doesn't know where the heroku `git` information is, so it returns `Couldn't find that app`.

What do I need to do to be able to run `heroku` in `cmd` from this folder? Or does it have to be a `heroku` git folder specifically?

Comment: What `Heroku` commands do you wish to run?

Comment: `heroku cert:add` for one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `heroku` CLI commands accept an `-a` / `--app` argument telling it what app to access, [e.g.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-certs-add-crt-key):

```
heroku certs:add -a your-app-here CRT KEY
```

As long as you provide that argument, you can run it from any directory. (Of course, this is still subject to authentication and authorization. You may need to run [`heroku auth:login`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-auth-login) before you can do this successfully.)

Comment: Thanks! Did not log in. It should return an error for that! Now I get `You need to be running on either Hobby or Professional dynos to be able to use SNI SSL.`. Do I seriously have to pay two companies to use SSL? I already paid for the cert..

Comment: @de-playable, that's a different question and [should be asked separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/248627). This answers your question of how to run `heroku` from an arbitrary directory.

Comment: But no, you don't need to pay two companies to use HTTPS. It rarely makes sense to pay for a certificate in 2020. You get HTTPS for free on `foo.herokuapp.com` domains, and for custom domains you can get free certs via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). The easiest way to do that on Heroku is via [its ACM service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management), which is included with paid dynos. If you go down this path, you only need to pay one company (Heroku, for a hobby-or-better dyno).

Comment: Since you have already unnecessarily paid for a cert, I guess you can try to get your money back. If you aren't able to do that then, yes, I guess you'll end up paying two companies to get this working (if you continue to host on Heroku). As far as I know, you do need to use at least hobby dynos to use SSL on a custom domain, either via ACM or a bring-your-own cert.

Comment: Okay, I will go down the ACM path - but, I still need to spin up an HTTPS node js server, no? Where will I get the certs? I've read through the docs and they don't mention any platform specific details.

Comment: `https://jaketrent.com/post/https-redirect-node-heroku/` seems to imply all traffic reaching node will be in http.. I'll just see what happens

Comment: @de-playable, you don't need to do anything else. ACM will provision a cert for you and route HTTPS requests to whatever you have listening on `PORT`. It will also handle renewals. (It _won't_ redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. If you want to do that, you need to do it in your application logic.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll start from the beginning from what I usually do when linking my github account/project with heroku.

I first upload and create a new project on github by using the following commands in the directory of my project:

1. Git init
2. Git add .
3. git commit -m “header”
4. git remote (SPECIFIC REPO)

Then once uploaded to git, perform the following to link with heroku:

1. heroku login
2. git push heroku master

After performing all these tasks (esepcially pushing to heroku master), you should be able to (in my case it worked) run heroku commands directly from your project directory in terminal.

Hopefully this was heplful.

Comment: Thanks - you're right. Problem was, I did not login to Heroku..!

Comment: If my answer was appropriate to your question, it would be greatly appreciated to mark this as answered and upvote it :) Glad I could help.